# How to implement a $1$-bit quantizer in Simulink?

Tags: modulation, quantization, simulink, delta-sigma

I am trying to implement a delta-sigma modulator block diagram in Matlab Simulink but can't find a $1$-bit quantizer (which is required in the modulator) anywhere. Could anyone please tell me how to go about it?

Comment: floor(.5*(sign(x)+1))

Comment: why do you need the `floor()` function, @StanleyPawlukiewicz?

Comment: Sign(0)=0.    Floor(.5)=0

Answer (score 1):

You can see [this example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/examples/sigma-delta-a-d-conversion.html) of Sigma-Delta A/D Conversion.